# Can we scan barcode and QRcode in SF1 app without clicking image

Tags: salesforce1-app, jquery

I have a requirement where I want to scan Barcode and QRcode from SF1 App something like https://andrastoth.github.io/webcodecamjs/

But the problem is, this is in `Javascript` and we are using `getusermedia()` method of javascript which is only supported in `Mobile chrome browser`. So if we test this in Chrome then it will work fine but I want to make this work in SF1 app. As we don't have much control in SF1 App so I am not quite sure if we can do this.  Can anyone have any idea please let me know thanks.

**Note:** There are many example available but in them we first need to click the photo which I don't want to use.